# How to Pass a Char Array (String) into a Linked List (Queue)

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a C program code that involves partitioning a sentence into separate words and putting those words into a linked list. My question is whether or not I should pass my data as a pointer or to the word array.

I've included parts of the code here. Some forums have said to use strcpy to pass the string, but is that in my *insert_at_foot function or in the data structure?

The test input is here, and I want to read in the last line after running scanf to get the dictionary (after the percentage sign)

```
#hewitt
5 95 0
#hugh
40 60 0
#jackman
0 100 0
#logan
40 0 60
#melbourne
5 5 90
#sydney
5 5 90
#zack
40 40 20
%%%%%%%%%%
hugh jackman is retiring the wolverine character after logan
```

Thanks all :)

```
typedef struct node node_t;

/* word of max letters stored in each data_t value */
typedef char data_t[MAXLETTERS];

/* listops.c */
struct node {
    data_t word; //dereferences the first letter in data_t[MAXLETTERS] 
    node_t *next;
};

typedef struct {
    node_t *head;
    node_t *foot;
} list_t;

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    ...
    while(scanf("%s", getword(word, limit))!=EOF){
        insert_at_foot(list, word);
    }

    while (!is_empty_list(list)) {
        word = get_head(list);
        printf("%s\n", word); 
        list = get_tail(list);
    }

    print_list(list);
  }

  list_t
*insert_at_foot(list_t *list, data_t word) { 
    node_t *new;
    new = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(*new));
    assert(list!=NULL && new!=NULL);
    //strcpy(new->data, word);
    new->data = word;
    new->next = NULL;
    if (list->foot==NULL) {
        /* this is the first insertion into the list */
        list->head = list->foot = new;
    } else {
        list->foot->next = new;
        list->foot = new;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Don't `typedef` arrays -- it will just confuse you to no end.... and don't `typedef` pointers either (same reason). You cannot assign strings (e.g. `new->data = word;`) is wrong. (*your compiler should be warnings you* if you are compiling with warnings enabled, `-Wall -Wextra` for gcc/clang, `/W3` for VS, at minimum). You must use `strcpy (new-data, word)`, because both `new->data` and `word` are `char*` in `insert_at_foot`, but you can't immediately tell that because you have typedeffed `typedef char data_t[MAXLETTERS];`

Comment: May I recommend to take a step back? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ You combine some concepts and it might help you to at first get comfortable with each of them. Practice your linked-list skills on e.g. integers or single characters. Then practice your skills with allocated memory and the involved pointers to them. Then practice string handling. Then start combining, e.g. strings of static length (or static maximum length) stored in a linked list. Then combine by using strings of dynamic length in allocated memory, referenced by pointers as data in linked lists.

Comment: Thank you Yunnosch and David, I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still struggling with the problem, you are not far off, but you can approach the read and parse of the information is an easier way based on the example data file your provided. If you look at the file, you only care about reading and separating the last line of data into words. Looking at all previous lines, they all begin with either a punctuation mark (`#` or `%`), while the last line begins with alphabetical characters.

While there are many ways to do this, a very effective way is to simply read each line into a fixed buffer (say `word`) using `fgets` (or POSIX `getline`), and then, using the tools from `<ctype.h>` test whether the first character `ispunct()` or `isdigit()`. If either tests `true`, simply read the next line. The simplicity of this approach means that when you exit the read loop, you have the last line contained in your read buffer. A simple implementation would be:

```
#define MAXLETTERS 256
...
    char word[MAXLETTERS] = "",   /* fixed buffer to hold each line */
        *p = word,                /* pointer to with for strtok */
        *delim = " \t\n";         /* delimiters to use with strtok */
    ...
    while (fgets (word, MAXLETTERS, stdin)) /* read/discard until last line */
        if (ispunct (*word) || isdigit (*word))
            continue;
        else
            break;
```

With the line contained in `word`, you can separate the line into individual words using `strtok` based on any delimiters you specify (`' '` and `'\n'`) make sense here. `strtok` returns a pointer to the beginning of each individual word and on each successive call, will point to the next word in the line. Your first call to `strtok` uses the name of the buffer containing your line, e.g.

```
    char word[MAXLETTERS] = "",   /* fixed buffer to hold each line */
    ...
    p = strtok (p, delim);        /* 1st call to strtok for 1st word */
```

each successive call uses `NULL` in place of `buf`, e.g.

```
    p = strtok (NULL, delim);     /* all subsequent calls use NULL */
```

When `strtok` reaches the end of the original string, it will return `NULL`.

(**note:** `strtok` modifies the string by inserting `'\0'` characters while tokenizing the string -- so make a copy of the original if you need to mainting the original string)

You then simply pass each token (individual word) to your `insert_at_foot (list, p)` function. You can combine all steps into a simple `for` loop as follows:

```
    /* tokenize last line using strtok */
    for (p = strtok (p, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim))
        insert_at_foot (list, p);   /* insert word in llqueue */
```

Within `insert_at_foot ()`, you cannot *assign* strings. As mentioned in the comments, one potential source of your problem is you have typedeffed an array, which masks the type for `word` in the function. It is simply `char*` and you must use `strcpy` to copy to `new->word` (**not** `new->word = word;`)

Fixing that and tidying up the function and adding a validation check for `list`, you could do something like:

```
list_t *insert_at_foot (list_t *list, char *word)
{
    node_t *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    assert (list != NULL && new != NULL);   /* validate both list & node */

    strcpy (new->word, word);   /* you cannot assign strings, strcpy */
    new->next = NULL;           /* initialize next to NULL */

    if (list->foot==NULL) {     /* check if list is empty */
        /* this is the first insertion into the list */
        list->head = list->foot = new;
    }
    else {  /* additional nodes added at foot */
        list->foot->next = new;
        list->foot = new;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Putting it altogether (and filling in for the functions you did not provide in your post), a working example could be similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAXLETTERS 256

typedef struct node node_t;

/* listops.c */
struct node {
    char word[MAXLETTERS]; //dereferences the first letter in data_t[MAXLETTERS]
    node_t *next;
};

typedef struct {
    node_t *head;
    node_t *foot;
} list_t;

list_t *insert_at_foot (list_t *list, char *word);

int is_empty_list (node_t *thenode)
{
    return thenode == NULL;
}

int main (void) {

    char word[MAXLETTERS] = "",
        *p = word,
        *delim = " \t\n";
    list_t *list = calloc (1, sizeof *list);    /* allocate list */

    while (fgets (word, MAXLETTERS, stdin)) /* read/discard until last line */
        if (ispunct (*word) || isdigit (*word))
            continue;
        else
            break;

    /* tokenize last line using strtok */
    for (p = strtok (p, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim))
        insert_at_foot (list, p);   /* insert word in llqueue */

    // print_list(list);
    node_t *iter = list->head;      /* temp node to iterate over list */
    while (!is_empty_list(iter)) {  /* while node not NULL */
        node_t *victim = iter;      /* temp node to free */
        printf("%s\n", iter->word); /* output word saved in node */
        iter = iter->next;          /* set iter to next node */
        free (victim);              /* free current node */
    }
    free (list);    /* don't forget to free the list */
}

list_t *insert_at_foot (list_t *list, char *word)
{
    node_t *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    assert (list != NULL && new != NULL);   /* validate both list & node */

    strcpy (new->word, word);   /* you cannot assign strings, strcpy */
    new->next = NULL;           /* initialize next to NULL */

    if (list->foot==NULL) {     /* check if list is empty */
        /* this is the first insertion into the list */
        list->head = list->foot = new;
    }
    else {  /* additional nodes added at foot */
        list->foot->next = new;
        list->foot = new;
    }

    return list;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/llqueue.txt
#hewitt
5 95 0
#hugh
40 60 0
#jackman
0 100 0
#logan
40 0 60
#melbourne
5 5 90
#sydney
5 5 90
#zack
40 40 20
%%%%%%%%%%
hugh jackman is retiring the wolverine character after logan
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/llqueue <dat/llqueue.txt
hugh
jackman
is
retiring
the
wolverine
character
after
logan
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/llqueue <dat/llqueue.txt
==22965== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22965== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22965== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22965== Command: ./bin/llqueue
==22965==
hugh
jackman
is
retiring
the
wolverine
character
after
logan
==22965==
==22965== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22965==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22965==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 2,392 bytes allocated
==22965==
==22965== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22965==
==22965== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22965== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions or if I misinterpreted your question in any way.

Comment: Thank you David again for the help. I posted my main function in the post below.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you David for your thorough response. I had missed this post, but I was finally able to finalize the part of this code using a char pointer, and using strcpy to copy the array of word into it. It works now. I am not familiar with strtok() from my class, but this code may be just as efficient? I have a couple more stages to work on using binary search trees and will update as I go. `int 
main (int argc, char *argv[]){

```
name_t name;        
name_t dict[MAXNAMES];

int limit = MAXLETTERS+NULL_BYTE;

list_t *list = make_empty_list();

char buffer[MAXLETTERS + NULL_BYTE];
char *word;

read_dict(&name, &dict[MAXNAMES]);

print_stage(STAGE3);

while(getword(buffer, limit) != EOF){
    //printf("Read a word: %s\n", buffer);
    word = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer) + NULL_BYTE);
    strcpy(word, buffer);
    //printf("%s\n", word);
    insert_at_foot(list, word);
}


char percent= ' ';

while (!is_empty_list(list)) {
    word = *get_head(list);
    printf("%s\n", word);
    free(word);
    list = get_tail(list);
}

print_list(list); //unlesss printf(&list)

printf("\n");
free_list(list);
list = NULL;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Yes, it will work fine and be equivalent in efficiency. You can either use `strtok` or just read a word at at time which I presume your `getword()` function does. You can also read a line at a time and just repeatedly call `sscanf` with a `%n` tacked on to the end to increment your line buffer position with. Lots of ways to do it. All fine. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Hello David, I posted my updated code, but I am confused over whether I can copy over a linked list to a new array, then perform the binary search on it, or just go via the linked list. Right now, I'm receiving a segmentation error

Comment: Technically, you are better off sorting an array than a list. If you want a sorted list, you generally add the nodes in sort order (that way you don't have to worry about shuffling `next->` pointer in a later sort). You can sort the list (either by swapping values or swapping nodes), but simply dumping the list values to an array, passing it to `qsort` and iterate over the list writing the values back to your list from the sorted array. I'll look at what you have and let you know.

Comment: Alright, thanks, well in this case, I'm not quite sure if qsort is needed, since I'm doing string comparison. I have updated my arguments, using dictionary array to compare with the array I've copied over

Comment: I have added a sort to my original answer [Sort Linked-list Queue via Array of Pointers](http://paste.opensuse.org/87994288). All I did was declare `char **sort;` (which is a pointer-to-pointer-to-char -- or -- pointer-to-char*) Then I added a count of the number of nodes (`size_t nnodes = 0;`) and counted nodes each time `insert_at_foot` was called. Then I simply allocate that many pointers `sort = calloc (nnodes, sizeof *sort);` and assigned a pointer to each `word`. Then simply passed the pointers to `qsort` for sorting (which leaves the original list unchanged) but the pointers sorted.

Comment: All new C programmers eyes roll-back when they have to write a `qsort` compare function to sort whatever they need to sort. They are not hard, but take understanding `qsort` will pass a `const` pointer to each element to the function for sorting  In this case it will be a pointer to `char *` (pointer-to-pointer). So before you use what `qsort` passes to the function in `strcmp` to alphabetically sort, you must cast the parameters back to `char *`. So you need a `char *word = *(char **)a,` etc.. (cast to `char **)` and dereference leaving `char *` which can then be compared with `strcmp`.

Comment: And yes, `qsort` can sort anything. That's the beauty. You simply write a compare function telling `qsort` how to compare whatever it is you wish to sort -- it does the rest. (extremely efficiently, and with years of testing and development). You just have to make friends with it -- it's well worth it. To handle strings, you just return the result of `strcmp` from your compare function -- that's it. By doing it this way, you end up with both the sorted array of pointers - and your original queue. Edit with your latest after you try qsort, I'll look in the morning -- brain is tired now...

Comment: Would having sorted pointers speed up the process of matching the word to the dictionary word? I want to ideally use binary search, and if the word in the sentence if found in my dictionary char array, then I would output whether it is a first/last name (the input shows the probability of whether it is a first, last, or non-name respectively). If the probability is 0 or not found, then the ouput is non-name.

Comment: Yes, you can use your sorted list with bsearch, which isn't a bad option at all. (rather good). The other optimal solutions would be a hash-table, see [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) and a *ternary tree* (used with many 'search as you type' routines for word suggestions, etc..) Also note you will write the same type of 'compare' function for `bsearch` as you do for `qsort` -- so go ahead and make friends with them -- there are many good Q's on SO about `qsort compare`.

Comment: If you really want to hurt your brain, then [Ternary Search Tree for Prefix-Search](https://github.com/drankinatty/ternary_st). The ternary tree is a modified TRIE with significant reduced storage requirements. It can search hundreds of thousands of words in about a micro-second.

Comment: Thank you for the references, but I am not sure I have the in-depth knowledge for executing hash tables/ternary trees just yet. I will keep those in mind though. I'm a biology student, so I am quite new to the C programming world and have done Java so far, which is why it's a bit more challenging to wrap my mind around some of these concepts. Nevertheless, I tried using qsort with error--so I have just stuck to binary search which compiled, but gave me segmentation faults, probably due to faulty memory allocation. If you could take a look, that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on using binary search to look through my linked list and, if a word is found in my dictionary as a first/last/ non-name, to print it out accordingly, such as in this test output. If not found, then it will print non-name. input/output

```html
#hewitt
5 95 0
#hugh
40 60 0
#jackman
0 100 0
#logan
40 0 60
#melbourne
5 5 90
#sydney
5 5 90
#zack
40 40 20
%%%%%%%%%%
hugh jackman is retiring the wolverine character after logan

=========================Stage 1=========================
Name 0: hewitt
Label probabilities: 5% 95% 0%

=========================Stage 2=========================
Number of names: 7
Average number of characters per name: 5.86

=========================Stage 3=========================
hugh
jackman
is
retiring
the
wolverine
character
after
logan
=========================Stage 4=========================
hugh                            FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
jackman                         LAST_NAME
is                              NOT_NAME
retiring                        NOT_NAME
the                             NOT_NAME
wolverine                       NOT_NAME
character                       NOT_NAME
after                           NOT_NAME
logan                           FIRST_NAME
```

I'm wondering whether it will be better to loop via my linked list or a new array since I've heard it's faster to do a binary search on an array. This is what I'm thinking (rough code):

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXLETTERS 30 
#define MAXNAMES 100
#define NULL_BYTE 1
#define EQUALSIGN 25
#define STAGE1 1 
#define STAGE2 2
#define STAGE3 3
#define STAGE4 4
#define STAGE5 5 
#define DICT_END '%'
#define EMPTY ' '
#define BS_NOT_FOUND (-1)
#define BS_FOUND 0

#define SIZE 50 //max of 50 words in the sentence
 
/* name and probabilities of name being first, last, or non-name word */
typedef struct{
 char name[MAXLETTERS+NULL_BYTE];
 int first_name, last_name, non_name;
 
} name_t;

typedef struct node node_t;

typedef char *data_t;

/* listops.c */
struct node {
 data_t data; 
 node_t *next;
};

typedef struct {
 node_t *head;
 node_t *foot;
} list_t;

/* dictionary array of name_t */
typedef name_t dict[MAXNAMES];

/* function prototypes */
void read_name(name_t *name);
void print_stage(int n);
void read_dict(name_t *name, name_t *dict);
int count_char(name_t *name, name_t dict[]);
int getword(char W[], int limit);
list_t *make_empty_list(void);
int is_empty_list(list_t *list);
void free_list(list_t *list);
list_t *insert_at_foot(list_t *list, data_t word);
data_t *get_head(list_t *list);
void push(list_t *list, data_t word);
list_t *get_tail(list_t *list);
void print_list(list_t *list);
void label_names(name_t *dict, list_t *list);
//int binary_search(data_t A[], int lo, int hi, data_t *key, int *locn);
int binary_search(name_t *dict, int lo, int hi, char A[], int *locn);
int compare (const void *a, const void *b);

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[]){
 
 name_t name;  
 name_t dict[MAXNAMES];
 
 int limit = MAXLETTERS+NULL_BYTE;
 
 list_t *list = make_empty_list();
 
 char buffer[MAXLETTERS + NULL_BYTE];
 char *word;
 
 read_dict(&name, &dict[MAXNAMES]);
 
 print_stage(STAGE3);
 
 while(getword(buffer, limit) != EOF){
  //printf("Read a word: %s\n", buffer);
  word = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer) + NULL_BYTE);
  strcpy(word, buffer);
  //printf("%s\n", word);
  insert_at_foot(list, word);
 }
 
 //char *array;
 //array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE);
 //strcpy into array
 
 int size=0;
 char A[SIZE]; //linked list copied
 //char *word;
 
 while (!is_empty_list(list)) {
  word = *get_head(list);
  printf("%s\n", word);
  A[size]=*word; //assign word to A[size]
  free(word);
  list = get_tail(list);
  size++;
 }
 printf("size %d array\n", size);
 
 print_list(list); //print the linked list and copies values of linked list to A[]
 //faulty print-list <-----
 
 /* stage 4*/
 int i, locn;
 
 print_stage(STAGE4);
 
 /* sort via the dictionary and *locn (index) in bsearch 
 run via each name in the linked list (i iterations) */
 for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
  printf("inside the loop");
  //run via all names in the dictionary
  if (binary_search(&dict[MAXNAMES], 0, size, A, &locn) == BS_NOT_FOUND) {
   printf("inside 1");
   printf("%s\t NOT_NAME\n", A);
  } else {
   printf("inside 2");
   //if statements to check whether it is a FIRST_NAME/LAST_NAME
   printf("%s\t NAME in A[%d]\n", A, locn);
  }
 }
 
 printf("\n");
 free_list(list);
 //list = NULL;
 
 return 0;
}

/* compare function for qsort to sort strings alphabetically */
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* a & b are pointers-to-char *, so you have to dereference to char* */
    char *word1 = *(char * const *)a,  /* could also use *(char **)a,    */
         *word2 = *(char * const *)b;
           
    return strcmp (word1, word2);
}

//run via each struct in dictionary array, compare char * with ones in linked list 
//A[] = linked list 
int
//name_t *dict = name_t dict[]  name_t dict[].name  = name_t **dict
binary_search(name_t *dict, int lo, int hi, char A[], int *locn) {
 int mid, outcome;
 //dict[count_names].name
 /* if key is in A, it is between A[lo] and A[hi-1] */
 if (lo>=hi) {
  return BS_NOT_FOUND;
 }
 mid = (lo+hi)/2;
 if ((outcome = strcmp(A, dict[mid].name)) < 0) { //string compare function
  return binary_search(&dict[MAXNAMES], lo, mid, A, locn);
  //run via all names
 } else if (outcome > 0) {
  return binary_search(&dict[MAXNAMES], mid+1, hi, A, locn);
 } else {
  *locn = mid;
  return BS_FOUND;
 }
}

/**********************************************/ 

//copy list to an array here
void
print_list(list_t *list){
 node_t *new = list->head;
 while (new){
  printf("%s", new->data);
  //A[size]=*new->data;
  new = new->next;
 }
 printf("\n");
}

/* store a single word in an array from the standard input, no longer than
limit characters, written by Alistair Moffat. Argument array is limit+1 characters */
int
getword(char W[], int limit) {
 int c, len=0;
 /* first, skip over any non alphabetics */
 while ((c=getchar())!=EOF && !isalpha(c)) {
  /* do nothing more */
 }
 if (c==EOF) {
  return EOF;
 }
 /* ok, first character of next word has been found */
 W[len++] = c;
 while (len<limit && (c=getchar())!=EOF && isalpha(c)) {
  /* another character to be stored */
  W[len++] = c;
 }
 /* now close off the string */
 W[len] = '\0';
 return 0;
}

list_t
*make_empty_list(void) {
 list_t *list;
 list = (list_t*)malloc(sizeof(*list));
 assert(list!=NULL);
 list->head = list->foot = NULL;
 return list;
}

int
is_empty_list(list_t *list) {
 assert(list!=NULL);
 return list->head==NULL;
}

void
free_list(list_t *list) {
 node_t *curr, *prev;
 assert(list!=NULL);
 curr = list->head;
 while (curr) {
  prev = curr;
  curr = curr->next;
  free(prev);
 }
 free(list);
}

/* Implementing a queue (FIFO) structure */
list_t
*insert_at_foot(list_t *list, data_t word) { 
 node_t *new;
 new = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(*new));
 assert(list!=NULL && new!=NULL);
 new->data = word;
 new->next = NULL;
 if (list->foot==NULL) {
  /* this is the first insertion into the list */
  list->head = list->foot = new;
 } else {
  list->foot->next = new;
  list->foot = new;
 }
 return list;
}

data_t
*get_head(list_t *list) {
 assert(list!=NULL && list->head!=NULL);
 return &list->head->data; //returns a char array of type data_t
}

list_t
*get_tail(list_t *list) {
 node_t *oldhead;
 assert(list!=NULL && list->head!=NULL);
 oldhead = list->head;
 list->head = list->head->next;
 if (list->head==NULL) {
  /* the only list node just got deleted */
  list->foot = NULL;
 }
 free(oldhead);
 return list;
}

/**********************************************/ 
 
void
print_stage(int n){ 
 int i;
 for (i=0; i<EQUALSIGN; i++){
  printf("=");
 }
 printf("Stage: %d", n);
 
 for (i=0; i<EQUALSIGN; i++){
  printf("=");
 }
 printf("\n");
}
  
//store name and percentage in name_t
void
read_name(name_t *name){ 
 
 print_stage(STAGE1);
 //can assume test input is valid
  
 /* consume the hash */
 getchar();
 
 name = (name_t *)malloc(sizeof(*name)*(MAXLETTERS+NULL_BYTE));
  
 /* ensure the program takes the correct input */
 assert(scanf("%s\n %d %d %d",  name->name, &name->first_name, 
  &name->last_name, &name->non_name));
 
 printf("Name 0: %s\n", name->name);
 printf("Label probabilities: %d%% %d%% %d%%\n", name->first_name, 
  name->last_name, name->non_name);
 
 free(name);
 name=NULL;
 
 return;

}
  
int
count_char(name_t *name, name_t dict[]){
 int count_char=0, i;
 for (i=0; dict->name[i]; i++){
  printf("%c ", dict->name[i]);
  count_char++;
  printf("number of chars is %d\n", count_char);
 }
 return count_char;
}

/* number of names and average number of chars per name */
void
read_dict(name_t *name, name_t *dict){ 
 print_stage(STAGE1);
 
 int i=0, j=0;
 double average;
 
 int count_names=0, count_char=0;

 name = (name_t *)malloc(sizeof(*name)*(MAXLETTERS+NULL_BYTE));
 assert(name);

 dict = (name_t *)malloc(sizeof(name_t)*(MAXNAMES));
 assert(dict);
 
 /* stage 1*/
 
 int c;
 
 //read a string of characters until you hit a percentage sign //%[^%]
 while ((c=getchar())!= DICT_END){ //consume the hash
  scanf("%s %d %d %d\n", dict[count_names].name, &dict[count_names].first_name, 
 &dict[count_names].last_name, &dict[count_names].non_name);

  count_names++;
   
 }
 
 while (getchar() == DICT_END) {
  /* do nothing */
 }
 
 for (i=0; i<count_names; i++){ // &
  for (j=0; j<dict[i].name[j]; j++){
   count_char++;
  }
 }
   
 printf("Name 0: %s\n", dict[0].name);
 printf("Label probabilities: %d%% %d%% %d%%\n",  dict[0].first_name, 
 dict[0].last_name, dict[0].non_name);
 
 free(dict);
 dict=NULL;
 
 free(name);
 name=NULL;
 
 /* stage 2 */
 print_stage(STAGE2);
 
 average = (double) count_char/count_names;
 
 printf("Number of names: %d\n", count_names);
 printf("Average number of characters per name: %.2f\n", average);
}

/**********************************************/
```